# Ask to Coredata if everything is well synchronized ? Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I need your help on a problem that I have for a little while of duplication in my entities.

Let me explain I have two entities that are in relationship (Item and Projects).
In my application when I launch it, I set up that automatically a Projects data that I would call "Inbox" is created so that I can add an Item data afterwards without having to create a List first.

The problem is that if I delete my app and reinstall it automatically the Projects "Inbox" will create when one already exists.
(my assumption is simply that my command is faster than launching Coredata is all the data from it).

So my question is. How to ask Coredata if everything is well synchronized to be able to ask him if I can create a Projects automatically (Inbox).

(here is a summary of my automatic order)

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Projects.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Projects.title, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isDefault == true")) var proje: FetchedResults<Projects>

if proje.count == 0 {
            let newC = Projects(context: self.viewContext)
            newC.title = String("\(inbox)")
            newC.isDefault = true
            newC.color = "lightGray"
            newC.id = UUID()
            do {
                try self.viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn’t you check this when the application is launched rather than when your view appears?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too but I don't know how to do it

Comment: The same way basically but use an NSFetchRequest instead

Comment: Should I replace FetchRequest with NSFetchRequest ?(I'm a noobie)

Comment: Yes, I would recommend you find an article or tutorial on how to use NSFetchRequest because it’s a very useful (almost required?) knowledge when using Core Data